# why does my for loop split words into individual letters during iteration in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I tried to pass the items in the dictionary below into a list
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4', "Zeke": "September 11", "Matt": "June 30"}
I used two methods
Method 1

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4', "Zeke": "September 11", "Matt": "June 30"}
dict_Birthdays = []

for k in birthdays.keys():
    dict_Birthdays += k
print(dict_Birthdays)
```

method 1 output = `['A', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'B', 'o', 'b', 'C', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'l', 'Z', 'e', 'k', 'e', 'M', 'a', 't', 't']`

method 2

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4', "Zeke": "September 11", "Matt": "June 30"}
dict_Birthdays = []

for k in birthdays.keys():
    dict_Birthdays.append(k)
print(dict_Birthdays)
```

Method 2 output : `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Zeke', 'Matt']`

I'd like to know in lay and detailed terms why method 1 has split my items into individual letters

Comment: To see what is happening, add more `print()` statements to your code. For example, you can add `print(k)` to see what the value of each value of `k` is.

Comment: You should use `dict_Birthdays.append(k)` because using `+=` treats `k` like an sequence the same way `some_list += [4, 5, 6]` would.

Comment: @Mark That's what they're using in the second example.

Answer (score 4):

`dict_Birthdays += k` is like `dict_Birthdays.extend(k)`. That expects `something` to be a sequence, and appends each element to the list. So it's equivalent to:

```
for letter in k:
    dict_Birthdays.append(letter)
```

This adds each letter as a separate list element.

Answer (score -1):

Your two examples are very different. In the first example, `dict_Birthdays += k` is equivalent to `dict_Birthdays.extend(k)`, but your second example uses `dict_Birthdays.append(k)`. The `extend()` method adds the elements of the given iterable to the list. In contrast, the `append()` method adds the given element directly to the list.